# Track amplitude sound of an ios device

Tags: ios, audio, tracking, microphone, amplitude

does someone knows a ios framework to track amplitude sound of a ios device. We need to do action when aplitude reach a level defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit it handles all of the audio functionalities. further, you can follow this tutorial for your requirements which I think I got.

LINK - https://audiokit.io/playgrounds/Analysis/Tracking%20Frequency/

Answer (score 0):

We facing issue with audiokit. As this is not a framework from apple, i wonder if this will not generate many code to fix. Thats why if something is available on the apple frameworks , think its better. Now if u can fix our issue, your help will be very apreciated. Contact trough $k-ype : emmanuel.drappier2